# how to write a Scala program to remove a row from a dataframe if it has same value as some other row for last column column?

Tags: scala, dataframe

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ant | kite | 123 |
| Bat | bite | 123 |
| Fly | gate | 211 |

here output dataframe should include

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Ant | kite |
| Fly | gate |

i.e since for col3 2rd row has same value as 1st row it should eliminate that row.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution using spark dataframe API.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

//sample dataframe
val df=Seq(("Ant","kite",123),("Bat","bite",123),("Fly","gate",211)).toDF("col1","col2","col3")
 
df.withColumn("rn",row_number.over(Window.partitionBy('col3).orderBy('col3)))
  .where('rn===1).drop('rn).show(false)

/* output
  +----+----+----+
  |col1|col2|col3|
  +----+----+----+
  |Fly |gate| 211|
  |Ant |kite| 123|
  +----+----+----+

*/
```